# Processing of the SQL statement ended

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a bunch of queries in my library (about 741 lines). I am trying to execute those queries into a new library. This is the code that takes all the queries and stores it into the string cVal and the executes them into the new library.

```
    while (rs.next()) { // Continue reading data until the condition is met

                for (int i = 1; i < col; i++) { // looping through the columns in order to get the data inside of
                                                // them
                    cVal = rs.getString(9);
                }
                PreparedStatement pt1 = conn.prepareStatement(cVal);

                pt1.execute();
                System.out.println(cVal);
                pt1.close();
            }

        }
```

About 430 lines get executed and then I come accross this error:

```
Unable to connect to database: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0952] Processing of 
the SQL statement ended.  Reason code 10. Cause . . . . . :   The SQL 
operation was ended before normal completion.  The reason code is 10.  Reason 
codes and their meanings are: 1 -- An SQLCancel API request has been 
processed, for example from ODBC. 2 -- SQL processing was ended by sending an 
exception. 3 -- Abnormal termination. 4 -- Activation group termination. 5 -- 
Reclaim activation group or reclaim resources. 6 -- Process termination. 7 -- 
An EXIT function was called. 8 -- Unhandled exception. 9 -- A Long Jump was 
processed. 10 -- A cancel reply to an inquiry message was received. 11 -- 
Open Database File Exit Program (QIBM_QDB_OPEN). 0 -- Unknown cause. Recovery  
. . . :   If the reason code is 1, a client request was made to cancel SQL 
processing.  For all other reason codes, see previous messages to determine 
why SQL processing was ended.
java.sql.SQLException: For all other reason codes, see previous messages to 
determine why SQL processing was ended.     at 
com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:710)    at 
com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:676)    at 
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonExecute
(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1021)  at 
 com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.execute
(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:1409)  at 
 Connection.main(Connection.java:49)
```

What would be the cause of this, I tried to google, but I wasn't able to find anything. Any help would be great thank you!

Comment: Your code makes no sense. --- What is the purpose of the `for` loop? The `cVal = rs.getString(9)` statement doesn't use `i`, so it might as well be outside the loop. --- `prepareStatement(cVal)`? You really read a SQL DML statement from column 9 of a `SELECT` statement and then just execute it? Wow!

Comment: Are there no error messages at all in your joblog? I would suggest that's the first place to look. (I am guessing that the sql statement you have reached is incorrect in some way - try running it from STRSQL or Run SQL Scripts.)

Comment: I was testing something with the loop, forgot to remove it. I am selecting from a library which contains multiple queries and executing them into another library. Do you have a better solution? Please do post it, so I can improve my code. @Andreas

Comment: @MandyShaw I have tried running the scripts individually and they work fine.

Comment: @Parth what about the joblog? Are there any error messages? I think there must be, that's indicated by the error 10.

Comment: Perhaps you should print `cVal` *before* trying to execute it, so you know what statement it is complaining about.

Comment: Also @Parth have you tried putting the script in a .sql file and running it from Run SQL Scripts?

Comment: I checked everything, @MandyShaw its telling me the same SQL query as shown in the error

Comment: @Andreas "cVal" isn't complaining what so ever... runs perfectly fine

Comment: 'Unable to connect to database' is interesting. Can you try running the sql script from Run SQL Scripts instead, as I suggested, to see whether this is a problem with your java (maybe a memory leak or something)? And what is in the joblog /before/ the message you have given?

Comment: This doesn't look at all correct to me.  Are you trying to running multiple statements in a single prepare and execute?  Is this possible?  Shouldn't the prepare and execute ALSO be in the loop?

Comment: @ParthMehta *"its telling me the same SQL query as shown in the error"* The error isn't showing any SQL, so how can you say that? --- *"`cVal` isn't complaining what so ever"* But `execute()` is complaining when it is trying to execute the SQL in `cVal`, so of course "`cVal` is complaining". --- Since `execute()` fails **before** the `println(cVal)` statement, you don't see the SQL that is failing. You see the previous SQL that didn't fail.

Comment: My bet would be on a long-running query hitting the query timeout.

Comment: What is the SQL that is getting error? Do you have any alter table commands as part of list?  Some of the SQLs  work fine when executed interactively thru STRSQL, but will fail when executed thru JDBC

Comment: I figured it out, there was alter query that was varchar(200) and the one after it was varchar(100). Having to reduce in size causes data losses, which is why it was complaining. It works fine now! Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: @ParthMehta Please mark this as answered. Thanks.